# Забить столбцы и строки значениями

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, g++

Знаю, вопрос для подавляющего большинства травиальный. Но я уже не вижу ошибки. Вроде все делаю как в примере.
Нужно заполнить строки и столбцы в динамическом двумерном массиве значениями(пока что одинаковыми). В выоде должна быть готовая таблица. Но у меня в выводе почему то все в одну строку.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int strings, columns;
std::cin >> strings >> columns;
int **aimarray = new int *[strings];  

for(int i=0;i<strings;i++){
    aimarray[i]=new int[columns];
}

for(int i=0;i<strings;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        aimarray[i][j]=1;    //заполняю строки и столбцы еденицами
    }
}

for(int i =0;i<strings;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        std::cout<<aimarray[i][j]<<" ";
    }
  }
 return 0;
}
```

объясните пжлст что я не так делаю. предполагаю что неправильно заполняю еденицами но не знаю как правильно

нужно чтобы вывод был примерно таким:

`1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1`
а у меня
`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну хотя бы так:

```
for(int i =0;i<strings;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        std::cout<<aimarray[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Вы просто не выводите никаких разделителей...

Comment: не совсем понимаю, как это повлияет на вывод виде строки-стлобцы?

Comment: @umd: Что значит "как"? Разбивать вывод на строки - ваша задача. Сам он разбиваться не будет. Вы вывели все в одну строку - получили одну строку, как и должно быть. И почему-то спрашиваете здесь, почему все вывелось в одну строку...

Comment: спасибо а ответ. мне нужно вывести не только строки но и столбцы. Я не понимаю как это сделать, ибо примеры так показывают

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать так, как я написал? http://ideone.com/nCYfuL - вот так? Если пробовали - то что за ерунду вы пишете? Если не пробовали - то попробуйте, а потом пишите свои теоретические "мне нужно вывести не только строки, но и столбцы".